# openssl_decrypt with aes-192-ctr return �L�� ��&A�C��

Tags: php, encryption, utf-8, character-encoding

I build a function to encrypt and decrypt an e-mail address to append it as a get param to an URL in the content of the e-mail.
When the recipient is clicking on the link in the email it should decrypt the get param so my site could work with this data again. I'm not allowed by different laws to save it till the user hasn't accepted the email.

so my code is working like this....

User is filling a form which posts the data to my function

```
SECURITY_SALT = "218391"; // just example salt
$email = $_POST['email'];
$getParamToAppend = openssl_encrypt($email, "aes-192-ctr", SECURITY_SALT);
sendMail($email, $getParamToAppend);
```

When the user is opening the URL of the mail it should decrypt and use this data again.

```
SECURITY_SALT = "218391"; // just example salt
$email = $_GET['email'];
$emailDecrypted = openssl_decrypt($email, "aes-192-ctr", SECURITY_SALT);
doMyStuff(emailDecrypted);
```

Now I'm receiving when I'm opening the URL out my Phone(Gmail) or a mail-client( https://de.tobit.software/david ) a result like this:

```
 myname@gma�L�� ��&A�C�� (gmail.com)
 myname@compan�L�� ��&A�C�� (david + 1&1 email address)
```

But when I'm opening the site with a 1&1 e-mail address via webmailer of my company I'm receiving

```
 myname@company.com
```

any ideas how to solve my problem?
tried till now different "solutions"

- utf8_decode/utf8_encode
- changing apache charset config
- different browsers

but nothing seems to work...

Additional Information: I'm using phpmailer and also set the Charset option to UTF-8 there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue by using this dope shit. ^^

before sending the e-mail

```
$getParamToAppend = openssl_encrypt(urlencode($email), "aes-192-ctr", SECURITY_SALT);
```

when clicking on the link

```
$emailDecrypted = openssl_decrypt(urldecode($email), "aes-192-ctr", SECURITY_SALT);
```